# Git <start-point> branch tracking remote automatically

Tags: git, branch

From the git docs,

`git checkout [-q] [-f] [-m] [[-b|-B|--orphan] <new_branch>] [<start_point>]`

`start_point` is defined as creating the new branch based on the commit from the starting point branch or commit, but in this specific case is also creating a branch that is tracking the starting point, for example:

`git checkout -b testbranch devbranch`

Outputs:

`Branch testbranch set up to track remote branch devbranch from origin by rebasing.`

Is this expected behaviour? shouldn't the `git checkout` just create a local branch that is not tracking any remote branch until specified? Is this a configuration i have enabled that is triggering this behaviour?

Comment: You set `branch.autoSetupRebase` to `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not expected behaviour. at last not in the way you have written your example:

```
git checkout -b testbranch devbranch
```

This should not set up any tracking even if `devbranch` is tracking a remote branch.

However, if you meant this command

```
git checkout -b testbranch origin/devbranch
```

Then that would be expected to set up tracking automatically. As stated in [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch):

> This behavior is the default when the start point is a remote-tracking branch

Also, you probably have set `branch.autoSetupRebase` to `always` or `pull.rebase` to `true` since you got the message "by rebasing" (instead of the silent default to merge).

If you wish to avoid this behaviour, and create a branch from the same commit that is pointed to by a remote branch, but not tracking that remote branch, you can run this command

```
 git checkout --no-track -b testbranch origin/devbranch
```